# How do I write these English sentences as quantified statements?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Sentence: Every integer can be expressed as the sum of three perfect cubes.

My attempt: ∀x∈ℤ

and then I don't know what to do for "sum of three perfect cubes" part.

Sentence: Every integer can be expressed as the sum of two distinct integers

My attempt: ∀x∈ℤ

and then I don't know how to do the "sum of two distinct integers"

Sentence: There exists a largest integer.

My attempt:  ∃x

and then I don't know how to "exists a largest integer"

Comment: I’m voting to close this for two reasons: (1) it is really three questions; and (2) knowing the symbols $\exists$ and $\forall$ hardly counts as an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists \{a,b,c\} \subset \mathbb{Z}\ {\rm s.t.}\ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = x$$

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists \{a, b \} \subset \mathbb{Z}\ {\rm s.t.}\ a \neq b \wedge (a + b = x)$$

$$\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}^+ {\rm s.t.}\ \forall x \neq y \in \mathbb{Z}^+ y > x$$

where of course $\mathbb{Z}$ represents the set of integers, and $\mathbb{Z}^+$ represents the set of positive integers, and ${\rm s.t.}$ means "such that."

One could use $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$, rather than $\{ a,b,c \}$, but I prefer the curly brackets which are clearer usage for a *set* rather than a tuple, which might imply some structure.  It means that *each element* in the set is in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Either way...

Comment: Thank you for your help. What does the ℤ s.t. mean?

Comment: "s.t" means "such that"

Comment: @FredVann:  Answered, but ummm... why did *you* use $\mathbb{Z}$ in your question?!

Comment: $\{a,b,c\}\in\Bbb Z$? Is it really standard? I have seen $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb Z^3$, or sometimes $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb Z$, which is already not pretty, but never $\{a,b,c\}\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @David G. Stork I was just wondering why another ℤ was used.

Comment: Should it not be $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq \Bbb Z$? I don’t think you mean $\{a,b,c\}\in\Bbb Z$ (unless it is nonstandard notation)

Comment: Can you name a math textbook written in the past 80 years that writes notation like $\exists\{a,b,c\}\in\mathbb Z$ instead of something like $\exists a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Not offhand... but it is the style/typography of *Mathematica*, which I use extensively.

Comment: For those wondering, **neither** $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}$ nor $\{a,b,c\}\in\mathbb{Z}$ are correct. The first example is a tuple of integers, so $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ would be correct. The second is a set, so $\{a,b,c\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ would be correct. To illustrate this point clearly it is best to use no parenthesis/brackets/braces at all and to write $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: First, Mathematica uses $\{a,b\}$ for ordered lists rather than sets, so that $\{0,0\}\in\mathrm{Disk}[]$ evaluates to `True` because $(0,0)$ lies in the closed unit disk. But Mathematica's treatment of $\in$ has a special exception that makes $\{2,3\}\in\mathbb Z$ evaluate to `True` for programming convenience. That doesn't make it proper mathematical style, just like Ruby's `elsif` command doesn't make "elsif" an English word.